# Prevent horizontal scrolling of background image

Tags: html, css

I have a page background image that must be aligned precisely in order to coordinate with the background image of a frame (so it looks like the same image over page and frame).  [Here is what it looks like](http://casaserena.heroku.com) (note the plant image).

The problem is that the page background image is making the horizontal scroll bar appear.  I want the horizontal scroll bar to appear when the window is smaller than the frame (#main_frame), not when the window is smaller than the page background image.

Here is the (SASS) CSS that (I think) is relevant:

```
#main_frame
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px
  -moz-border-radius: 25px
  border-radius: 25px
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.7)
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 0px #706270
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 0px #706270
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box
  box-sizing: border-box
  background-color: white
  border-style: solid
  border-color: black
  border-width: 2px
  width: 950px
  margin: 50px auto
  height: 800px
  background: #fff url(../images/plant_white.jpg) 560px -95px no-repeat

#plantBackgroundHolder
  width: 1200px
  height: 900px
  background: #ffc url(../images/plant_yellow.jpg) 690px -40px no-repeat
  position: absolute
  z-index: -1
  top: 0
  margin-left: -600px
  left: 50%
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="plantBackgroundHolder">
  <div id="main_frame">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm pretty sure it's the width of the #plantBackgroundHolder that is causing the horizontal scroll bar to appear; but if I remove that, the background image gets shifted around.

*Background information:*

1. [The original solution for making a transparent overlay effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701078/overlay-transparent-image-over-clickable-links)
2. [The site with the problem](http://casaserena.heroku.com/)
3. [The repo of the site](https://github.com/curiousyogurt/Casa-Serena)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring a height here and there on your CSS, you need to remove that, you need to let the height flow freely instead of setting a fixed height. Here are the places i could find:

```
body { height: 1000px } // remove height, also width!!!
#plantBackgroundHolder { height: 900px } // remove height
```

Moreover, remove the margin that you have set on the #main_frame id and set it to something like `10px auto 0` to remove the margin you have set on the bottom of the div.

Also, remove this from your `html` tag, you're forcing the scroll to appear on the page;

```
html { overflow-y: scroll }
```

Note: you need to heavily revise your code, you're not properly nesting your divs and you can easily achieve the same effect with less than half of what you have now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I implemented your suggestions, but the problems still remain (see repo for revisions).  Any other ideas?

Comment: You still need to fix the #main_frame id's margin, you're still adding 50px's to the bottom, change that piece to something like "10px auto 0" and it should fix that piece, the extra space that you have underneath is just the shadow effect you have spanning the whole box.

Comment: Thank you again.  Changing the margin of #main_frame does fix the bit at the bottom; but the problem of how to stop the horizontal scroll from appearing when the browser's window width is smaller than the background of #plantBackgroundHolder still persists.  That's what I'm trying to solve.  Perhaps there is no way to fix this problem?

Comment: I think I made some progress: I can stop the horizontal bar from appearing by setting the background on the body selector in css.  But then it doesn't move when the window is resized horizontally, and it mismatches with the image in the frame (except when the window has exactly the right size to line up).

Comment: You will need to break down all of your code and rewrite it once again properly, you're not taking the css box-model into account here and you're nesting things improperly. To start, you're not utilizing the #container id of your code, it is there to properly size and position all of your content (you can fix those horizontal scrollbar issues you're having by positioning that box dead center of your page, using "#container { margin:0 auto; width:950px; }" and removing all positioning styles you have set for your #plantBackgroundHolder id.

Comment: I can go on and on but you need to take into account the [CSS box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) and revise your code, i suggest a full rewrite. But if you're tight on schedule and looking for a quick fix you can replace that "overflow: auto" style you currently have set for your html tag and set it to "html { overflow-x: hidden }" ...of course, this will only hide it, which is not recommended as you're not taking into account all viewport sizes and is manually positioning the container "according to your screen size" (remember, css is supposed to do that automatically).

Comment: I took your suggestion and revised the code; I'm not on a tight schedule.  Thanks for taking the time to look at the code and results.  Any other specific suggestions?  I've managed to use a combination of your `html {overflow-x: hidden}` suggestion and Javascript to show the horizontal scrollbar — the problem is that when the scrollbar appears, it's still too long.  But it seems to be the closest I can get.  Any ideas how rewriting further will help?  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply, was handed a big project that is eating up all of my time. Just took a look at your page and it looks great!, So, to answer your question "Any ideas how rewriting further will help?", as for any code, a tidier and cleaner code is always easier to maintain and easier to debug whenever you have a problem, as you have it now you are not taking into account two divs which are the #container and #main id's, you can cut down on a lot of your css by using them and clean up your code a bit, to avoid headaches in the future, and for semantics sake it is more correct.

Comment: @curious: At the moment your book now button is breaking to the next line in FireFox 5, if you change the padding on this rule to `ul li {display: inline;font-size: 14pt;padding: 0 16px;}` it should fix it. Also you can delete in your html the `#container`, `#header`, `#main` and `#flash` divs as they are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Working to align the two images might keep coming back to haunt you. One approach is to use a single image with a transparent background. PNG's with alpha transparency work since IE6 ([more info](http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6/)).

Sandwich the png between the white background behind the content and the border around the content. Here is an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ansonhoyt/c7j22/).

```
/* Container provides (yellow) background behind the image */
#main_frame_container {
    position: relative;

    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

/* Position the "background" image */
#background_image {
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
    top: -10px;

    width: 100px;
}
/* Main content over both the (yellow) background and image */
#main_frame {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: solid black 2px;
    padding: 20px;
}

body {
    background-color: pink;
}
```